# StyleCop custom rule to validate new List(size);

Tags: c#, string, design-patterns, stylecop, static-code-analysis

How can I check the syntax "**new List(size);**" from a code? size can be any numeric value to define the List size. this is to create a custom rule in StyleCop. I could go with regular expressions as well. what is the best way to solve this pattern. need to show a warning if developers use this pattern to initialise a List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^new(\s{1,})list(<(.*)>)?\((\d+)?\)(\s+)?;(\s+)?$` demo @ https://dotnetfiddle.net/DOC4pz